# Android: After orientation change breaks connection between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

Application has two fragments: the first one contains a small representation of pager with photos, and the second one contains full screen pager. The second fragment replaces the first and passes a page number to the previous every time it changes. I made connection between my fragments just like [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) says.

Everything works till device orientation doesn't change. The first fragment is not recreated until it is not on top of stack, that is why all page number changes after that are missed for first fragment.

I do not really what to disable views destroy on orientation change, but looks like it is the only way.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file in your parent activity in which fragments are write following line :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

Let me know if that works for you. Best of luck :)

Comment: Yes, it can help to solve this problem. I knew about it. But I am looking for solution when fragments are recreated and connection between them established again.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the orientation, the activity gets rebuild, thus essentially destroying the fragment that was built before the change in orientation.

Perhaps you would wish to refer to this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html on retaining the state during a change in configuration.